# downloaded chromeDriver but my visual studio code still ask me to downloaded chromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/et_on/Documents/Eoyzyc's Code/AMZN_Search_TC_001.py", line 4, in 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "C:\Users\et_on\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\et_on\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding it. It is asking you to download chromedriver because it can't find one in the path you added to.

Change this to your actual chromedriver path :

```
webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Set this to your actual file directory where it's located.  For example :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/intel/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Path to where chromedriver.exe found.

If chromedriver.exe on Documents :
You can add to path like : C:\Users\User\Documents

How to add to path: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html